# I just updated my Windows Phone 8 device and now I can't debug on it. Do I need to do something?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I try to run the app via Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone I get the error message:

> The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the
>   target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed

It worked 10 minutes ago, until I updated with OS version

```
8.0.10328.78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by deploying the solution to the phone first by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Deploy Solution", and then running the app to debug.

I don't know why it's required to deploy the solution first. This wasn't required before the update when I ran the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following:

1) Developer unlock the phone once more

2) Uninstall your application from the phone by hand, and build it again